# React with jquery does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am trying to integrate swiper plugin in my react component and the css is working but when i click in the arrows the slider does not working, its seems like the js code of the swiper does not run.

```
var Swiper = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount() {
    let el = this.getDOMNode();
    let swiper = new Swiper(el);
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="swiper-container">
        <div className="swiper-wrapper">
          <!-- Slides -->
          { this.props.children }
        </div>
        <div className="swiper-button-prev"></div>
        <div className="swiper-button-next"></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var Post = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="swiper-slide">{this.props.title}</div>
    );
  }
});

var Posts = React.createClass({

 render() {
    return (
        <Swiper>
          <Post title="1" />
          <Post title="2" />
        </Swiper> 
    );
  }
});
```

fiddle: http://jsbin.com/ramugenoqe/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: any error in your dev console? can you reproduce in a fiddle?

Comment: This is the problem no errors.

Comment: Here is fiddle http://jsbin.com/ramugenoqe/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/tituxeruka/1/

Here's a working JSFiddle.

The main problem is that your component is called Swiper.

```
var Swiper = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount() {
    let el = this.getDOMNode();
    let swiper = new Swiper(el);
  },
```

`let swiper = new Swiper(el)` tries to create a instance of the React component rather than the actual plugin. To Solve this simply change the name of the component so there is no naming collision (see fiddle).

I'm not familar with Swiper but I also changed the setup to reflect the docs I found here http://www.idangero.us/swiper/get-started/#.VS43-fnF8X8 to pass in a class selector and config object.

Comment: How to do this for functional component